# How would I go about abandoning this patent application?

Tags: pro-se, intellectual-property, office-action, response, abandonment

I filed a patent application as a pro se inventor and I've now received an office action. Between the filing date of the application and now, I've discovered that I don't have a need for this patent application and I would like to abandon the application entirely.

How do I respond to this office action so I can successfully abandon this patent application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need not do anything. It will become abandoned by your failure to reply in time ([37 CFR 1.135(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/37/1.135)).

Nevertheless, if you want, you can expressly abandon your application by filing a letter to this effect ([37 CFR 1.138](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/37/1.138)). However, if you do this, there's little chance of reviving it later. It would therefore be a pretty rare case that this is a good idea, and perhaps only to avoid publication.